# Search flights by stopping location

Tags: flight-search-engines

I'm looking for a platform where you can easily search for flight by origin and **stop location**,
Is there such a thing?

I would appreciate any help

For example: 
The search I want to do - 
The all flights on a specific date **from VIE** TO Everywhere **VIA WAW**

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "stop location"?

Comment: Are you asking for a search engine that will help you find hidden-city routings?

Comment: I clarified my question

Comment: If you book a ticket from VIE to KBP via WAW, and there is some delay or cancellation, the airline may change you to a non-WAW route. They will have fulfilled their responsibility if they get you from VIE to KBP more-or-less on time. Would that be a problem for your plans?

Comment: This may be a problem,
But we will rely on luck and statistics.

Comment: You can just look at WAW departures, then.

Answer (score 2):

The apps/sites I use – Google Flights and Skyscanner – have a multi-city option where you can add individual legs as you need or see fit. For example recently, I searched for a return trip where I specifically wanted the outbound leg to stop over in Helsinki for 24 hours. Three flights in the multi-city option and boom.

In your case, however, you can simplify the procedure. You know that you want to fly Vienna–Warsaw–anywhere with LOT and its partners, so just go to any app or site (Skyscanner, Google Flights, etc.), select Warsaw to anywhere, set the departure time to a comfortable cushion after the Vienna–Warsaw flight arrives, preferably select LOT as the airline and off you go. Then backtrack to make sure the entire ticket from Vienna is sold as one.